# how to write a .htaccess with RewriteRule multiple file and multiple site?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi everyone i am making multiple sites script using php framework, but I have a problem with my .htaccess.
I have the following code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# -- domain1.com --
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1\.com$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ domain1.com-sitemap.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap-page.xml$ sitemap_main.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^favicon.ico$ domain1.com.ico [NC,L]
# -- domain1.com --

# -- domain2.com --
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2\.com$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ domain2.com-sitemap.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap-post.xml$ sitemap_main.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^favicon.ico$ domain2.com.ico [NC,L]
# -- domain2.com --

# -- domain3.com --
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain3\.com$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ domain3.com-sitemap.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap-allpost.xml$ sitemap_main.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^favicon.ico$ domain3.com.ico [NC,L]
# -- domain3.com --
</IfModule>
```

my .htaccess only works on the first RewriteRule in each site.

when I try open http://domain3.com/favicon.ico or http://domain2.com/favicon.ico on my browser, that appears is the favicon of the first domain

I would appreciate any help/ideas!

Thank you.

Comment: You RewriteRules are conflicting with one another.

Comment: To be more clear, only the first rule for each domain will get noticed for each of the three conditions. So requesting sitemap.xml will work for the three different domains, but the second two rules for the first domain will always be used for all three domains.

Comment: so, how to fix them if i want all RewriteRules working?